# Can't give play/pause commands to any player running in background

Tags: python, linux, audio-player

I am trying to make a widget in python for linux that can *play/pause* the current song, adjust volume, toggle songs,etc.

So far, I am able to get the process names of music players running in the background using ***media.role*** property of pulseaudio. But I am unable to give shell commands to each of them because the options are different for each player.

```
import subprocess as sp

output = sp.check_output("pacmd list-sink-inputs", shell=True)

index = 0
while index>=0 and index<len(output):
    first = output.find("role = \"music",index+1)
    index = first
    if index<=0:
        break
    index = output.rfind("properties",0,index)
    test = output.find("application.name",index)
    index = output.find("process.id",index)
    index = output.find("\"",index)
    index = index+1
    index2 = output.find("\"",index)
    num = output[index:index2]
    print "pid="+num
    proc = sp.check_output("cat \"/proc/"+num+"/comm\"", shell=True)
    proc = proc[:-1]
    print proc
    index = output.find("media.name",index2)
```

Output:

```
pid=9895
gmusicbrowser
```

Maybe I am approaching it from the wrong direction, but the objective is to make it run with any player.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Why aren't you using D-Bus for this?

Comment: I didn't know about it.